# Mysql(db design) - storing invoices that starts from 1 each year

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best way for storing invoices in one table. Primary key is autogenerated but invoice number starts from number 1 on each year.

Is this OK?

```
invoces
------------------------------------------------
`id`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`invoice_number`  int NOT NULL ,
`year`  year NOT NULL ,
etc...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Invoice number column is starting from 1 on year start.

Thanks :)

EDIT:
Problem: How to determin when a year ends/starts ?

Idea: Create another table for years. When time comes close year (set column for example for 2010 set opened=0) and add a row for new year (for example set field opened=1 for 2011).

New schema:

```
invoces
------------------------------------------------
`id`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`invoice_number`  int NOT NULL ,
`fk_year_id`  year NOT NULL ,
etc...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

```
invoces_year
------------------------------------------------
`id`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`year`  year NOT NULL ,
`opened`  tinyint NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: the invoice number should be the primary key - why would you want to reset this each year ??

Comment: @f00: Because that's how customer wants it. Period.

Comment: @Both - that's Italians for ya

Comment: @f00 - there is also the scenario where invoice is randomly generated INT or they decide to change and allow alphanumeric invoices. Lots of reasons to have separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. That's fine. I do it like that. Having UNIQUE key on (year, invoice_number) will help avoid accidental errors.

One more thing you should consider is: if the invoice is ever 'cancelled' or 'deleted', will you want to allow for 'recycling' the number used or not. If yes, then the setup can get a bit more complicated.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but I'm prettu sure your queries could also benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your primary key a compound field of invoice_number and year.

This removes the need for the autoincrementing ID.

Comment: On the other hand using a single field PK, which is in no way bound to business data is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use a compound key **and** an auto incrementing invoice number.

```
create table invoices(
   year           int not null
  ,invoice_number int not null auto_increment
  ,primary key(year, invoice_number)
);

insert into invoices(year) values(2009);
insert into invoices(year) values(2009);
insert into invoices(year) values(2009);

insert into invoices(year) values(2010);
insert into invoices(year) values(2010);
insert into invoices(year) values(2010);

select * 
  from invoices;

+------+----------------+
| year | invoice_number |
+------+----------------+
| 2009 |              1 |
| 2009 |              2 |
| 2009 |              3 |
| 2010 |              1 |
| 2010 |              2 |
| 2010 |              3 |
+------+----------------+
```

The downside (and I personally think this is big) is that there is no easy way of porting that behaviour to other databases.

**Updated**
As pointed out in the comments, the "reset behaviour" **only works with MyISAM** tables. This is an even bigger downside because you won't be able to use InnoDB (which you should for this kind of data).

Comment: Also note this will only work with MyISAM. I'd be hard pressed to store invoice data in not ACID compliant tables.

Comment: I've been thinking about compound key...and still...thinking...I'd rather avoid if possible...still thinking...

Comment: @Mchl, crap! You're right! I now remember that I have read it in the documentation, but at that time I was using myisam :) (Answer updated to reflect this)

Comment: :) Nevertheless, I appreciate the response

Answer (score 0):

Another way of performing this would be to create the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices(
invoiceyear int,
invoiceid int AUTO_INCREMENT ,
amount decimal,
PRIMARY KEY ( invoiceyear, invoiceid )
)
```

The result of this is that each year a new invoiceid is reset automatically. The result would be something like this:

```
invoiceyear invoiceid   amount
2011    1   1
2011    2   1
2011    3   1
2010    1   1
2010    2   1
2011    4   1
```

However, it should be noted that if you delete an invoice and the invoice has the latest number for that year then this number will be reused. However, if you remove invoice 3 above this will not be reused.